# How do you say bicycle kick in Russian?

Tags: значения

How do you say bicycle kick in Russian?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Удар_через_себя_в_падении](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

> Удар через себя в падении, или бисиклета (порт. bicicleta; также распространено название «удар „ножницами“»)

Answer (score 1):

В основном, все говорят “удар через себя».